# Lists of lists: why does changing value at a[1][0] also change a[0][0]?

Tags: python, list

Can anyone please explain what is happening here? I understand python `int`s are assigned by value (and not by reference).

```
>>> alist = [1,2,3]
>>> a = [[0]*3]*4
>>> a[0][0] = len(alist)
>>> alist.append(1)
>>> a[1][0] = len(alist)
>>> a[0][0]a
4
>>>
```

Comment: Off topic: Naming your variables as reserved words (*list*) is a recipe for disaster **:-)**

Comment: There are less *different* list objects than are expected: `[] * x` *does not* preform a "deep copy".

Comment: The problem is that if I edit a[1][0] I don't expect a[0][0] to take the same value.

Comment: The list problem has been fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a list using the `*` notation, you're repeating the same element. Not *copies* of the element, but the same exact object.

When the object you're repeating is immutable, such as an integer, you won't notice.

When the object is mutable, such as a list, you get *the same* list repeated. If you make a change to one list you're making it to all of them.

In your case you made a change to element `[1]` and it was reflected in element `[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your outer list contains multiple copies of the same inner list value. Here's how you can tell:

```
a = [[0]*3]*4
print(a[0] is a[1]) # prints True
```

If you want a two dimensional list of zeros, I suggest using a list comprehension for the outer part so that you get separate inner lists instances:

```
a = [[0]*3 for _ in range(4)]
print(a[0] is a[1]) # prints False

a[0][0]=1
print(a[1][0]) # prints 0
```

Comment: Ok that explains everything! I must say this syntax is rather confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This might help (just dumping the values of `list` and `a` at each line):

```
#With some commentary
>>> alist = [1,2,3] #Created a list with 3 elements
>>> alist
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a = [[0]*3]*4 #Created a list with 3 copies of one element and then copied it 4 times
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0] = len(alist) #Set the 0th element of the 0th copy to 3
>>> a #Now you can see where that value was copied
[[3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0]]
#The rest is just a permutation of that first 'bug'
>>> alist.append(1)
>>> alist
[1, 2, 3, 1]
>>> a[1][0] = len(alist)
>>> a
[[4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]
4
```

An unintuitive thing about this code might be that `[0]*3` seems do do what you expected while `[[0]*3]*4` did not.  For this I can only guess (not a Python guru yet) that a single length list of ints was handled in a way that seemed intuitive, while a list of lists fell back to a copy approach.

Comment: Don't use names of built-ins for your variables, i.e. `list`.

Comment: +1 @MarkRansom. that too!

Comment: Mark, I think we'll all agree with you. But that comment is clearly better given to the OP. This poster is just trying to help the OP understand using their own terms.

Comment: I realize it was that way in the original question, but you should fix it in your answer.

Comment: well i do want to only access one element at a time. How should I do then?

Comment: @JasonSperske  This is the *start* of a good answer - however, spell out *what* is occurring instead of just providing the output that takes "some interpretation" to understand.

Comment: Well it follows my thought process. I thought that a[x][y] was the regular way to access/write data in a 2D list in Python. I did not imagine this would be the behavior

Comment: @JulesTestard, your approach to accessing is correct, it was your initialization of `a` that gave the odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. `[[0]*3]*4` created a list with 4 copies of a list of 3 elements. a[0], a[1], a[2] and a[3] all point to the same list.

```
>>> a=[[0]*3]*4
>>> a
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> a[0][0]='hello'
>>> a
[['hello', 0, 0], ['hello', 0, 0], ['hello', 0, 0], ['hello', 0, 0]]
>>> for mylist in a:
    ...     print id(a)
    ...
    42701168
    42701168
    42701168
    42701168
>>>
```